# calculation technical

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

am looking the kinect calibration and depth calculation.

(http://www.ros.org/wiki/kinect_calibration/technical)

z = b*f / d

There is "4.1 Focal lengths".

IR focal length is 580 pixels.

Could you please tell me why camera focal length is used in terms of pixels

instead of in mm or in meteres ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40697/calculation-technical/) by [rosmaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2491/rosmaker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-08-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rosmaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2491/rosmaker/) on 2012-08-06**:
Sorry. I know that former question doesn't uploading. It is closed

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2012-08-07**:
I'd recommend editing the title to something a bit more relevant (focal length in pixels etc..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It does not matter whether the focal length is given in pixels or mm, as the relationship is determined by the sensor and image sizes. Go through the following link for more details: http://www.bobatkins.com/photography/technical/measuring_focal_length.html

In general, it is a good idea to have the focal length in pixels as the image size is generally known. Knowing the full [intrinsic camera matrix](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html) allows for independence from the image size as well.

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2012-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0